# Can I have the build dialog in the center of the screen?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe6

Ever since Delphi XE2 (or even before) the build dialog appears in the bottom right corner of the screen.
Because I'm a curious fellow I'd like to see what's going on.
But that's hard when it's way there in a corner.

[image]

If I move the dialog to the **correct** centered position the IDE does not register/remember this and keeps on putting in in the corner every time it compiles.

**Is there a way/hack to make this dialog appear in the center of the screen?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enabled background compilation: *Tools | Options | Environment Options | Background compilation*.

[image]

The designers presumed that you did that because you did not want the compilation progress to disturb you, and stop you being able to see the editor window. The whole point of background compilation is for you to be able to carry on working in the IDE whilst compilation progresses. If the dialog was shown in the middle of the IDE window then you would not be able to see what you were working on.

If you disable background compilation then the dialog will appear in the centre of the monitor.

Comment: Aha, now it makes sense. Thanks. I figured the background compilation would run in the background whilst I work.  Something akin to the way it works in Eclipse.

Comment: It does run in the background whilst you work. That's why they put the dialog off to the side, and made it partially transparent.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but not as quietly as in Eclipse. The dialog as currently implemented just adds to much visual distraction to allow you to work whilst it's running.

Comment: I personally agree with that, but I'm just the messenger. I think that the progress should appear in a status bar.